In prisma, how to add a custom field on query result?
I have an implicit many-to-many relation: User and Post. A user could like many posts, and a post could be liked by many users.
Here is the schema:
model User {
  id         String    @id @default(dbgenerated("uuid_generate_v4()")) @db.Uuid
  posts      Post[]    @relation("author")
  likes      Post[]    @relation("like")

  @@map("users")
}

model Post {
  id         String    @id @default(dbgenerated("uuid_generate_v4()")) @db.Uuid
  author     User      @relation("author", fields: [author_id], references: [id])
  author_id  String    @db.Uuid
  comments   Comment[]
  likedBy    User[]    @relation("like")

  @@map("posts")
}

Now I want to get the post lists to render. For every post, there will be a heart showing if it's already liked by current user. How could I get a structure with type Post & { isLiked: boolean } ? It would be perfect if it could be done in one query.
Further more, since the type Post & { isLiked: boolean } is not imported from prisma, where should I store the type? I want to follow the single source of truth rule.

You cannot have computed fields on prisma, but you can work around this by extending the prisma client. You can find an example here.
